# Conditional Boolean If statement syntax in ruby

Tags: ruby, boolean

I want the push elements of an API into my array if the condition for an attribute is true. So `k_api_hash['awsaccounts'][i]['sandman']` will return `true` or `false` and, if the condition is true, I want to push the account number in to an array; `(k_api_hash['awsaccounts'][i]['accountnumber'])` will return an account number.

**Code**:

```
k_api_hash = JSON.parse(kens_api)
aws_account_size = k_api_hash["awsaccounts"].size
aws_account_array = []

i = 0
while i < aws_account_size
  if k_api_hash['awsaccounts'][i]['sandman'] == "true"
    aws_account_array.push(k_api_hash['awsaccounts'][i]['accountnumber'])
    i += 1
  else
    i += 1
  end
end

puts "Here are all the aws accounts"
puts aws_account_array.inspect
```

The problem is that it is returning null value, but successfully pushes the account numbers into the array if the `if` condition is taken out.

**Output**:

```
Here are all the aws accounts
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if` is returning `false` every time because you are comparing `"true"` (*String*) with `true` (*TrueClass*) / `false` (*FalseClass*); consider the following code:

```
true == "true"
#=> false

false == "true"
#=> false

true != "true"
#=> true
```

To make it work simply remove `== "true"`<sup>1</sup> from your `if`:

```
if k_api_hash['awsaccounts'][i]['sandman']
```

<sup>1</sup> Remember that any expression in an `if` that returns `true`/`false` (or a *truthy*/*falsey* value for that matter) needs no further comparison.

---

Not related to the error, but your code could be optimized by using a different iterator and removing unnecessary variables; for example, the following code will yield the same output:

```
k_api_hash = JSON.parse(kens_api)

aws_account_array = k_api_hash["awsaccounts"].each_with_object([]) do |account, r|
  r << aws_account_array.push(account['accountnumber']) if account['sandman']
end
```

To understand better what is going on, take a look at [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do the job:

```
k_api_hash = JSON.parse(kens_api)
awsaccounts = k_api_hash['awsaccounts']
aws_account_array = awsaccounts.reduce([]) { |array, acc|
  array << acc['accountnumber'] if acc['sandman']
  array
}
```

If the API is returning string booleans like `"true"` or `"false"` you could do a hash like:

```
  bools = {true=>true, 'true'=>true}
```

and call it using what api returns as key inside the reduce

```
  array << acc['accountnumber'] if bools[acc['sandman']]
```

Comment: I don't think that `bools` hash is necessary, according to OP the API will return either `true` or `false`, so there is no need to check for `"true"` (or `"false"`) .

Comment: You could leave a side note to give the option to OP, no harm in giving extra info. :)